# Google Tango- camera area learning

Tags: android, google-project-tango

i am currently developing an application that uses Google Tango with the java programming language on Android studio. Right now i am testing on the area learning function, how can i access the tango camera that is use to save an ADF file.

Answer (score 0):

The cameras are not directly used to save an ADF. Tango is build on different cameras RGB, ToF and Wide-Angle.

What you can access are the relevant properties of those, called camera intrinsics and extrinsics, like described here:
https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/intrinsics-extrinsics